# Javascript: How can I delete data automatically from firestore based on timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Now I am building an e-commerce project.
I have the product records in "Product" collection in firestore.
And the collection has limit field.
The field value is timestamp.

What I want to achieve is, to delete the data automatically in "Product" collection when the time limit comes.

For example, if you are a user, you can buy products before the time limit.
But after the time limit comes, the product data will be automatically deleted from the collection and disappear from the website.

> How can I delete the data automatically from the collection at the
> certain time. I am using javascript.

I read some articles about the time scheduler of firestore cloud functions, but I could not find the way to accomplish this.

If you have any idea of it, I would like you to share the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this.

First way to do is that you can use a Scheduled Cloud Function. You can find relevant example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) and [here](https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/)

second way to use cron job. You can write a cron job which will call after every 15min let say and it will check that current time is less than your product's timestamp. So when current time will be greater than your product's timestamp so simply delete your product data from Firebase.